# How to create select_box for a has_one relationship in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I have the following model:

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores, through: :store_platform_associations
end
```

,

```
class StorePlatformAssociation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store
  belongs_to :platform
end
```

and

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :platform, through: :store_platform_association
end
```

I'm developing a form to included a `Store` using [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form).

At this form, I'm trying to include a `Store` and let the user select one from many displayed platforms.

To show available platforms, i'm using:

```
<%= f.input :platform, collection: Platform.all %>
```

But, when I submit the form, i'm getting this error message:

```
Internal Server Error
expected Hash (got String) for param `platform'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try using the `:platform_id` instead of `:platform` for the form input?
Just like in the documentation of [collections in simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not SimpleForm that is causing the issue, but the way you set up your associations.

You specify a `has_one :through` and a `has_many :through` association, without the `belongs_to` association.

The way I would set up these associations is like this:

For the `Platform` model:

```
class Platform < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :stores
end
```

For the `Store` model:

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :platform
end
```

This allows you to use the [associations with SimpleForm](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#associations):

```
<%= f.association :platform %>
```

This renders a select box with the platforms. You might want to specify the method that needs to be used for the labels of the platforms:

```
<%= f.association :platform, label_method: :name %>
```

Comment: Hi @JanDintel. Thanks for your answer, but I forgot to mention the `StorePlatformAssociation` class. Now, i've added it to my question.

Answer (score 0):

**Nested Association**

The problem you have is that you're trying to set the `object` of `Platform` with a string (typically `id`), which is getting your Rails backend confused!!!!!!!

Here's the deal:

```
#app/models/store.rb
Class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :platform ...
```

This means that the `platform` attribute of your model object is actually populated by the associative data contained within the `platform` model. This translates into *setting* the value for this, too.

--

**Fix**

I THINK that What you'll want to do is to set `platform_ids` in your `collection` select:

```
#app/views/stores/new.html.erb
...
<%= f.input :platform_ids, collection: Platform.all %>
```

I don't think you'll have to set the param, although you may wish to do it to test:

```
#app/controllers/stores_controller.rb
Class StoresController < ApplicationController
   ...
   private

   def store_params
      params.require(:store).permit(..., :platform_ids) #-> I don't think you'll need this
   end
end
```

Here's a [reference to the `platform_ids` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#module-ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods-label-Collection+associations+%28one-to-many+%2F+many-to-many%29)